# Jenkins Pipeline - Groovy string function to remove trailing comma

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Probably a super easy one to answer, but in a a Jenkins Pipeline script, what string function can I use to strip off a trailing comma from a string I have defined.

For example:

`def fooBar = 'foo, bar,'`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the comma is the last character, as in the hardcoded literal that referenced in the question, you could do something like this:

```
def fooBar = 'foo, bar,'
def result = fooBar[0..-2]
```

If you don't know the comma is the last character, you could find it by doing something like `fooBar.lastIndexOf(',')` and use that value to retrieve the characters before and after the comma and concatenate them.

Comment: Thanks, before you answered I actually used the substring string function instead and that works a charm for me

Comment: "I actually used the substring string function instead and that works" - Makes sense.  `fooBar[0..-2]` is Groovy shorthand for getting a substring that begins with the first character and ends with the second to the last character.